# How can I determine my XYZ position?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm currently doing a "mini farlands-or-bust" thing in one of my worlds, and I was wondering, how can I determine my XYZ position? I tried doing the math with the file size, but that won't work now the the view distance adjusts automatically. So, how can I determine my XYZ position?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a mod, you can enter the following command:

```
/tp @p ~ ~ ~
```

That teleports you to where you are and it would say in the chat:

```
Teleported [your username] to [x], [y], [z]
```

---

## [1.12](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_1.2.0) Update

You can show coordinates on the screen as long as `gamerule showCoordinates` is `true`.

```
/gamerule showCoordinates true
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do is I use [block launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.zhuoweizhang.mcpelauncher&hl=en), as it allows you to install and use game mods. One of the mods I have is called [smooth minimap](http://mcpe4u.com/smooth-minimap-mod/), it adds a small map to the screen, it also displays your xyz in-game.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following method, you do not need commands.

Go into settings and turn on "Show Coordinates"